# Return join table attributes in incluce with loopback

Tags: loopbackjs

I've got a data structure fairly similar to the one described on the Loopback [HasManyThrough](https://docs.strongloop.com/display/public/LB/HasManyThrough+relations) documentation page.

For a given Physician (e.g. id 2), I would like to get all their patients with an appointment AND their appointment date.

I can do a `GET` operation like this:

`GET /physicians/2`

with the `filter` header `{ "include" : {"relation":"patients"} }`

And I do get the physician, and the list of patients, but I lose the `appointmentDate` of the relation.

Or, I can do a `GET` operation on the relation table like the documentation shows:

`GET /appointments`

with the `filter` header `{ "include" : {"relation":"patient"}, "where":{"physicianId":2}} }`

And I get the the appointments, with the date and the patient embedded, but not the physician details.

I can't seem to be able to combine the two.

Is there a way to get the whole data with one query?

The data would be something like this:

```
[
    "name" : "Dr John",
    "appointments" : [ {
        "appointmentDate": "2014-06-01",
        "patient": {
          "name": "Jane Smith",
          "id": 1
        }
    }]
]
```

One <strike>way</strike> hack I found is to define the relation twice. Once as a `HasManyThrough` and once as a `HasMany` to the appointments table, then I can do something like this:

`GET /physicians/2`

with the `filter` header `{ "include" : {"relation":"appointments","scope":{"include":["patient"]} } }`

But that doesn't seem right, or could maybe lead to odd behaviours with the duplicated relation.. but maybe I'm paranoid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could include both models

```
GET /appointments
{ "include": ["patient", "physician"], "where": { "physicianId":2 } }
```

You will get quite a lot of duplicate data though (details of physician with id 2). I believe, that [HasManyThrough](https://docs.strongloop.com/display/public/LB/HasManyThrough+relations) relation model was initially not supposed to carry any extra data and therefore, it has some limitations. [Here](https://github.com/strongloop/loopback/issues/466) is a related github issue.

Comment: Thanks Ivan, that confirms things. I hadn't found that github issue, and the related SO question, both good reads.