# How to nested include through models relationships LOOPBACK?

Tags: loopbackjs, strongloop, loopback

Lets continue with the Patient - Physician analogy from the Loopback Docs. Let's make the assumption that Physician model looks like this:

```
{
   "id": "4654654654654654654",
   "name": "John Doe"
}
```

and Patient model looks basiclally the same (only id and name) and two models are connected with HasManyThrough relationship with through model called Appointment as in the docs. https://loopback.io/doc/en/lb2/HasManyThrough-relations.html

My question is, when you GET to /api/physicians url how can you query the response so it includes the appointment date as well as patient for every physician?

Wanted output:

```
{
  "id": "4654654654654654654",
  "name": "John Doe",
  "patients": [
     { "id": "1321232313", "name": "First Patient", "appointment_date": 1995-12-17T03:24:00 },
     { "id": "1321232313", "name": "Second Patient", "appointment_date": 1995-12-17T03:24:00 }
  ]
}
```

Field "appointment_date" is the date from the appointment through model and patient names are obtained through nested including of same model.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Return join table attributes in incluce with loopback](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36394736/return-join-table-attributes-in-incluce-with-loopback)

Comment: It is similar question indeed, but the point of my question is how you can get the list of all Physicians, and within every Physician obj the list of all Patients with respective appointment dates. The question you mentioned is about getting all data about one instance of Physician querying with the psysician id.

Comment: GET /api/physicians?filter[include]=patients

Answer (score 3):

Use **Nested Include** Just check [link](https://loopback.io/doc/en/lb2/Include-filter.html) Its help.

Please check this Code :

```
    physicians.find(
{
  include: {
  "relation": "Appointment",
  "scope": {
    "fields": ["id", "patientId", "AppointmentDate", "physiciansId"], /*need to include both Person and PersonID fields for this to work*/
    "include": {
      "relation": "patient",
      "scope": {
        "fields": {"id": true, "patienName": true},
         where: {id: patientId},
      }
    }
  }
}
}
```

Comment: nested filtering of objects using _where: {id: patientId},_ is not possible in relational db as of now with lb. you can just include fields

Comment: Please check Link that i provide with title "LoopBack supports that with the following syntax (for example):" i think its possible.

Comment: check these two issues the documentation is wrong https://github.com/strongloop/loopback/issues/517 https://github.com/strongloop/loopback/issues/683